# How to fire an update per new row in kdb+/q?

Tags: time-series, kdb, dataflow

I am trying to create a service whereby irregularly spaced events from several sensors are aggregated into 1 second time buckets/ sample rate (seen as though not doing so would be computationally expensive/memory intensive), when a second passes i.e. a new row is formed I would like to fire/trigger an event/ publish the last row that is received by subscribers according to the kdb+ tick architecture.
[image: KDB+ tick architecture]

From what I understand from stream processing one should buffer the events before running an aggregation, my question is how one should implement this in kdb+/q whereby after the completion of a specific time interval (1 second in this instance) an aggregation can be performed on the latest buffered data, the results of which are appended to a table/sent to subscribers that contain regularly spaced aggregations of the irregular sensor data, clearing the buffer in the process.

So in simple terms:

1) How can one implement buffering functionality that collects irregularly spaced events, whilst maintaining memory constraints?

2) How can one aggregate the irregularly spaced events accurately at an interval forming regularly spaced aggregations of the buffered events and sending that aggregation to subscribers?

(My interpretation of the functionality herein could be completely wrong, If there is a better way to achieve this, that would be great!)

Your advice on this matter would be truly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The kdb tick architecture already has this functionality baked in - specifically by setting a non-zero timer in the command line on startup - in your case `-t 1000` for a one-second timer. This alters how the timer function `.z.ts` is defined and alters how the `.u.upd` function is defined. In the batching scenario it stores updates in-memory until the next run of the timer function when it publishes the data to subscribers. So you could create a chained tickerplant with this same logic and have it batch/store and then aggregate before publishing

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the primary tickerplant running in non-batch (raw) mode so that you don't throw away data

Comment: Thanks for the response terry, however it would seem that conducting a batch aggregation of the data for each tick would be wasteful. So from what I can garner from your response is that one would only query data that has arrived during the aforementioned interval. i.e. select price from trades where time >= interval_time; ?

Comment: Wasteful in what sense? It would not aggregate on each tick, it would aggregate on each run of the timer (1 second). I believe this achieves what you want but maybe I'm not understanding your problem fully. The batched chained tickerplant will: 1. receive all incoming records and store/buffer in in-mem tables 2. Every second will take the buffered data and aggregate (you'll have to add this in as a customisation) and will publish downstream. Note you don't have to filter on time, you take everything from the buffered table then 3. Wipe the buffered table and start accumulating again

Comment: Some info here: https://code.kx.com/v2/kb/chained-tickerplant/

Comment: If you require your aggregations to be within more strict intervals - e.g. precisely within 09:45:00 and 09:45:59 then you would need to filter on time and would need to widen the timer window to greater than one second so that you have enough wriggle room to contain an entire minutes worth of data in memory

Comment: Ah! of course, thanks

Comment: Thanks, found the documentation on chained ticker plants to be quite helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terry is correct in his comments, a TP will batch in periods specified by the timer when launching the process. For example, to run a vanilla TP with 1 second batching would be as follows.

```
q tick.q sym  .  -p 5010 -t 1000
```

I would strongly recommend against doing any processing within the TP, it should act as a point of ingress and the creator of logs for recovery. Whether to run the TP in a batch mode or in zero latency (not supplying a `-t` parameter) is dependent on the nature of the updates you receive, the whitepaper on [tickerplant throughput optimization](https://code.kx.com/v2/wp/kdbtick_profiling_for_throughput_optimization.pdf) is your best bet for advice here.

You could have chained tickerplants in which you perform further aggregations or computations, but I would personally opt to have a Realtime Engine (RTE) operating as follows

1. RTE is a subscriber of the TP for the table to be aggregated on (e.g., `trades`)
2. Aggregations could be performed with `.z.ts` or be triggered from the time data of the table, the former being much easier to implement. These aggregations are part of the aggregations table, distinct from the original data table, say `tradesAgg`
3. The final stage of the aggregations would involve publishing back to the TP. This ensures your TP log file contains the history of all data that has entered or been produced by the system.
4. Your RDB would be subscribed to this aggregation table and through
   the RDB, the data would enter your historical database

Comment: Hey Callum perhaps didn't take full note of your logic with respect to the RTE, truly helpful thanks!

Comment: Is there perhaps any literature/code in which an RTE as you have described exists, truly appreciate your guidance

Comment: There is limited documentation on them, but essentially one would be an RDB without the capability to perform EOD actions, (so set end::()). You would also have to add the functionality to publish back to the tickerplant, in a format it can accept (i.e.,like the feedhandler).  Like an RDB it will be subscribed to the TP for the table in question.